# How to add height and width dimensions automatically to archive descriptions

Tags: functions, images

I have this code which adds height and width data for images in *posts and pages*:

```
function add_img_size($content){
  $pattern = '/<img [^>]*?src="(https?:\/\/[^"]+?)"[^>]*?>/iu';
  preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $imgs);
  foreach ( $imgs[0] as $i => $img ) {
    if ( false !== strpos( $img, 'width=' ) && false !== strpos( $img, 'height=' ) ) {
      continue;
    }
    $img_url = $imgs[1][$i];
    $img_size = @getimagesize( $img_url );
      
    if ( false === $img_size ) {
      continue;
    }
    $replaced_img = str_replace( '<img ', '<img ' . $img_size[3] . ' ', $imgs[0][$i] );
    $content = str_replace( $img, $replaced_img, $content );
  }
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','add_img_size');
```

However, this code *does not* add in height and width data for any images that are present in *tag descriptions or category descriptions*.

Question: how can I edit this code so that tag descriptions and category descriptions are also included in the filter/function above and images in tag/category descriptions have height and width data added automatically?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd strongly avoid using `@` in code in the way this code has ` $img_size = @getimagesize( $img_url );`, `@` doesn't prevent errors, it hides them, the error still happens. Not only that, but `getimagesize` on a URL is going to make a HTTP request, which is a major performance hit, would it not be better to add the attributes on save so it only needs to be done once? `the_content` runs every time the post is displayed

Comment: That's interesting, but not entirely related to the question. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Images in taxonomy descriptions are not native to WP - so is this for a 3rd party theme?